# Python requests waits for key input before executing

Tags: python, terminal, python-requests, virtualenv

I'm learning python. Currently writing some test app that needs to get some html from other site and display it in my browser. For this I'm using:

- virtualenv with python 2.7
- flask as my web framework
- requests to get the html

Every time I run the app and refresh the page I need to go to the terminal and press enter in order to continue. How do I stop it? I want it to execute automatically.

There is no special example or some special code in question. Running standard requests.get(someURL). Then I see the URL in question in my terminal (that I used to start virtualenv and flask app) and the execution continues only after I hit enter in terminal.

```
from flask import Flask
import requests

@route("/")
def test():
    return start_req()

def start_req():
    r = requests.get('https://example.com')
    #now it waits me to hit enter in terminal
    return r.text
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve], it's unreasonable to expect someone to guess the problem.

Comment: shoe your code. where do you run it ? in console, in some editor ? do you get any message when you have to press enter ? did you read this text ? maybe you have some error message or other usefull information but you didn't read it.

Comment: What's running in the terminal? The client requests script or the server script? Try hitting ctrl-C, maybe you'll get a stack trace showing the line of concern.

Comment: There is no special example or some special code in question. Running standard requests.get(someURL). Then I see the URL in question in my terminal (that I used to start virtualenv and flask app) and the execution continues only after I hit enter in terminal. I have updated my question.

Comment: What happens if you run the `flask` process in a separate window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, because I'm noob I didn't know my .py files should end with enter. I believe that that solved the problem.